# Can the PC SPECIALIST Vortex Minerva II Gaming PC be turned on its side?

Tags: desktop-computer

I have a slight space issue and was wondering if the *PC SPECIALIST Vortex Minerva II Gaming PC* could be turned on its side when used.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it does not matter - as long as you don't move the computer around when it's turned on.

As far as I am aware - the only thing that could possibly suffer are HDDs (magnetic hard-drives).

Find out if you have any inside and use google to find datasheet for your HDD model - it should include information on preferred mount orientation, if there is any.